# AWS Cognito JWK throws error but other oauth2 endpoints are fine

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, spring-security-oauth2, jwk

I've just configured my custome domain for AWS congito and wanted to connect my Resource Server (Spring Boot). Since I received a 400, I crosschecked the Endpoint manuelly and received the same response: [Postman attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNvFX.png).
Did anyone encounter this issue working with AWS Cognito custome domains?
Did I miss something?

Comment: A few days ago I saw very slow responses from .well-known endpoints. After some time I found that on another device (with a different Internet provider) it works fine. So I guess that some limits or throttling were applied to my IP. I rebooted router (so new dynamic IP was assigned to my workstation) and it works fine now.

Comment: The response returns in around 350 ms, also at other devices. It seems like its related to cloudfront.

Comment: I see you are using http, have you tried https? And have you tried url like this `https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/.well-known/jwks.json` for getting JWKS info?

Comment: @YuriyP Thank you, with https and the user cognito path its working. Any idea why the jwk-set path of a custome domain cant be resolved? I'll try to handeled the issue by an additional dns entry for now.

Comment: No, I don't know why JWKS path doesn't use a custom domain. I just use URLs provided by open id configuration endpoint `https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/.well-known/openid-configuration`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a custome domain at cognito, the jwks path needs to be accessed the classical way: https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/.well-known/openid-configuration